# Why is the commutator of ladder operators non-zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, harmonic-oscillator, commutator

Griffiths states that the "ladder" of stationary states for a harmonic oscillator should be unique. That should mean that for one particular energy level, there exists only one energy state. So if I have an energy state $\psi$ with energy $E$, $a_+ \psi$  should take me to a state with energy $E + \hbar \omega$, and $a_- a_+ \psi$ should have energy $E$. And similarly, $a_+ a_- \psi$ should have energy $E$. Shouldn't this imply that $a_+ a_- \psi = a_- a_+ \psi$, since they both correspond to the same energy? What is wrong with the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The up-down $\sim$ down-up property  implies only that that $a_+a_- \psi= \lambda a_-a_+ \psi$ for some number $\lambda$.   Here  $\lambda$ can be (and indeed *is*) a number other than 1.

Comment: But then what does it mean for the ladder to be unique?

Comment: We have $a_+|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1} |n+1\rangle$ and   $a_-|n\rangle = \sqrt{n} |n-1\rangle$ so $a_+a_- |n\rangle =(n+1)   a_-a_+ |n\rangle$. No problem with uniqueness.